# How to trigger and event on a particular div?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a section in my page

```
<section>
....
1
</section>
```

I need to increment the count from 1 to 10000 for which I have some javascript code -- http://jsfiddle.net/CPtTQ/1672/.

Now I need to increment the count when I scroll to the above section.

So far I have tried

```
<section #myDiv (click)="getCounter()">
</section>

 @ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef;
     triggerFalseClick() {
     let el: HTMLElement = this.myDiv.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
     el.click();
 }
```

Comment: What was the result of what you have tried? Compared to what was expected? Just a question: is there a special reason to trigger a "false" click on the div instead of calling `getCounter()` manually?

Comment: Actually I have seen triggerFalseClick() somewhere and I have used that. That's not working. When I scroll to that particular section or div can I call getCounter()